# How To Create a paragraph in Text View?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

Does anyone know how to create a Paragraph in text view. I'm trying to learn Xcode and by trying to learn I'm making an app. I Want it to look like: (When i type it in it looks like this but it won't come out like this.

"  Engine Specs:
 VQ37CHR - 3.7 Liter DOHC 24-Valve V6
 332hp @ 7,000rpm
 276 lb-ft @ 5,200rpm 
Nismo Tuned Dual Exhaust
 Twin intake System

Drivetrain:
  Carbon Fiber Drive Shaft
 6-speed close-ratio Manual Transmission 
7-speed Automatic w/ manual shift mode, paddle shifters and rev matching
 VLSD
  4-wheel vented disc brakes
 2-link Double wish bone Suspension front
 4-link Suspension rear 
front and rear Stabilizer bars"

But it keeps coming out Like one giant paragraphs like This:

"The 5th Generation in the Z family.  Engine Specs: VQ37CHR - 3.7 Liter DOHC 24-Valve V6 332hp @ 7,000rpm 276 lb-ft @ 5,200rpm Nismo Tuned Dual Exhaust Twin intake System  Drivetrain:  Carbon Fiber Drive Shaft 6-speed close-ratio Manual Transmission 7-speed Automatic w/ manual shift mode, paddle shifters and rev matching VLSD  4-wheel vented disc brakes 2-link Double wish bone Suspension front 4-link Suspension rear front and rear Stabilizer bars"

I'm a noob at this sorry.

Upadted `textView.text = @"The 5th Generation in the Z family.\nEngine Specs:\nVQ37CHR - 3.7 Liter DOHC\n 24-Valve V6\n332hp @ 7,000rpm\n276 lb-ft @ 5,200rpm\nNismo Tuned Dual Exhaust\n\nTwin intake System\n\nDrivetrain:\nCarbon Fiber Drive Shaft\n6-speed close-ratio Manual Transmission\n7-speed Automatic w/ manual shift mode, paddle shifters and rev matching\nVLSD\n\n4-wheel vented disc brakes\n2-link Double wish bone Suspension front\n4-link Suspension rear\nfront and rear Stabilizer bars";`<-- I'm putting this into the view FirstViewController.m is this the right place to put it?

Comment: You need to clarify what you're actually doing. Try showing code.

Comment: Added the code (Based fichek's help). Im Trying to separate lines of text, like paragraphing. its always the simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` aka newline character. Put it in your text where you want new lines to be, like this:

```
textView.text = @"Engine Specs:\nVQ37CHR - 3.7 Liter DOHC 24-Valve V6\n...";
```

Comment: textView.text = @"The 5th Generation in the Z family.  \nEngine Specs: \nVQ37CHR - 3.7 Liter DOHC\n 24-Valve V6 \n332hp @ 7,000rpm \n276 lb-ft @ 5,200rpm \nNismo Tuned Dual Exhaust \nTwin intake System \n \nDrivetrain: \nCarbon Fiber Drive Shaft \n6-speed close-ratio Manual Transmission \n7-speed Automatic w/ manual shift mode, paddle shifters and rev matching \nVLSD \n \n4-wheel vented disc brakes \n2-link Double wish bone Suspension front \n4-link Suspension rear \nfront and rear Stabilizer bars";

Comment: You can't have actual new lines in your text (I can see them when I copy/paste the code from your comment), you need to replace them all with `\n` like this: `textView.text = @"The 5th Generation in the Z family.\nEngine Specs:\nVQ37CHR - 3.7 Liter DOHC\n 24-Valve V6\n332hp @ 7,000rpmn276 lb-ft @ 5,200rpm\nNismo Tuned Dual Exhaust\nTwin intake System\n\nDrivetrain:\nCarbon Fiber Drive Shaft\n6-speed close-ratio Manual Transmission\n7-speed Automatic w/ manual shift mode, paddle shifters and rev matching\nVLSD\n...";`

Comment: And that Goes into the Code? not into the text view. Thank you for helping me. its always the simple things lol.